# Using Blogger's layout tags to rearrange post

Tags: html, blogger

Here's the blog: http://testingfaraway.blogspot.co.uk/

I'm aiming to simply rearrange how the first post listed on the blog is displayed, placing the post title at the top rather than the post image. Example of before and after:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/phqLe.png

However I've struggled to understand how to achieve this through Blogger's layout tags, here's the code:

```
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
<div class='post hentry'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
        <h1 class='post_entry_title'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
                <a expr:href='data:post.link'>
                    <data:post.title/>
                </a>
                <b:else/>
                <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                    <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
                        <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
                            <data:post.title/>
                        </a>
                        <b:else/>
                        <data:post.title/>
                    </b:if>
                    <b:else/>
                    <data:post.title/>
                </b:if>
            </b:if>
        </h1>
    </b:if>
    <b:else/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
            <h2 class='post-title entry-title'>
                <b:if cond='data:post.link'>
                    <a expr:href='data:post.link'>
                        <data:post.title/>
                    </a>
                    <b:else/>
                    <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
                        <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
                            <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
                                <data:post.title/>
                            </a>
                            <b:else/>
                            <data:post.title/>
                        </b:if>
                        <b:else/>
                        <data:post.title/>
                    </b:if>
                </b:if>
            </h2>
        </b:if>
    </b:if>
</b:if>

<div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<data:post.body/>
<b:else/>
<div expr:id='&quot;p&quot; + data:post.id'>
    <data:post.body/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an actual firstpost conditional tag in Blogger, that should solve your problem.

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
  <!-- first post markup -->
<b:else/>
  <!-- if not first post markup -->
</b:if>
```